# Rails 4 - How to populate remote content in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is what I have

I have a method like this in my `bookmarks_controller.rb`

```
def fetch
   @result = LinkThumbnailer.generate(params[:url])
end
```

I have the following form fields to create new bookmarks

1. url
2. title
3. description
4. thumbnail
5. tags

So my `new.html.erb` looks like this

```
<%= form_for(@bookmark, :html => {class: "panel-body"}) do |f| %>
    <% if @bookmark.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@bookmark.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this bookmark from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @bookmark.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="block">
      <%= f.label :url, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <%= f.text_field :url, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'URL' %>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <%= f.label :title, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Title' %>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 6, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Description' %>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <%= f.label :thumbnail, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <%= f.text_field :thumbnail, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Thumbnail url' %>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <%= f.label :tag_list, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <%= f.text_field :tag_list, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'Tags (separated by commas)' %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-info" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I would like to have a button called `Fetch` right next to `url` field.

When user click `Fetch` button, I would like to populate the form fields using ajax.

I viewed rails documentation.  It says to add `remote: true` attribute to the form.

But I wanna use ajax function only when the user click fetch button.

Can someone help me with this?

Thankyou

Comment: From where do you fetch the data to populate the form fields? Are you using jquery?

Comment: What do you mean by 'populate'?

Comment: @RafaelRamosBravin I guess he means give the fields a value.

Comment: @AndreasLyngstad I figured, but we could use a litle more information about how he want's to populate them

Comment: @AndreasLyngstad Yes. I'm going to use jquery.

Comment: @RafaelRamosBravin I mean filling the fields with returned content. For example `fetch` action returns 3 values when i pass the url. I can access the values like this `@result.title, @result.description, @result.thumbnail`

Comment: Will you need to pass something as a parameter to your action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate an object using the [LinkThumbnailer](https://github.com/gottfrois/link_thumbnailer) gem and than convert it to json
with this action:

```
   def fetch
     @result = LinkThumbnailer.generate(params['given_url'])

     respond_to do |format|
       format.json do 
         result.to_json
       end
     end
   end
```

And in your view you could use the Jquery [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method to access the #fetch action and pass the given url as a parameter:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   require(['jquery'], function($) {
     $('.fetch-button-class').change(function() {

       var given_url = $('.url-class').val();
       $.getJSON('<%= fetch_action_url %>', {'given_url': given_url }, function(obj) {

         $('.title-class').val(object.title);
         $('.description-class').val(object.description);
       });
     });
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: Actually I need to pass url to fetch the content. I'm not querying anything from the database.

Comment: @Giri  With wich data will you populate the fields than?

Comment: Yes everything. Actually its like this. Its a bookmarking site. Some users are lazy. So i'm giving an option to fill the content automatically with one click.

Comment: So instead of typing title and description, they have the option to fill the content with one click

Comment: This is the gem i'm using to fetch title and description https://github.com/gottfrois/link_thumbnailer

Comment: @Giri You should update your question with that info